Curve in tabbar
enter image description here
I want to design tabbar like this, I got this design from design team and want to make this type of design in Flutter project
For now I'm showing default design
Curvature of the Tab Bar:
How precise should the curvature of the underline be? Do we need any specific design guidelines for the curves, or is an approximation sufficient?

Refer this answer hope its help to you.

This sounds like more of a design question than coding, can you provide more info about your project e.g. code sample of your HTML markup, any styles you're using etc?

Hey, I got this design from the design team and want to make this in flutter project, and I don't know how to start this
